# Installing and Configuring Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2015 On-Premise and Accessing it Externally

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, windows-server

What are the things to consider/needed when Installing and configuring Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2015 on-premise and accessing it externally?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How would you want to access it externally? remote login or using a browser pointing to your on-premise? if you have access to you local network externally nothing really changes. Otherwise you will have to do an IFD. (Internet facing deployment) of you CRM solution with ADFS.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. What I wanter is to access it using a browser pointing to my on-premise crm. I already tried the IFD but when I try to access it externally, it didn't work. I don't know what's the problem. I also try to ping the url that I configured but it can't be reached.

Answer (score 2):

Should you want to expose your on-premise address to the internet( if this is what you mean by 'externally') - you'll have to look into `IFD` - `Internet Facing deployment`.

[Step-by-Step instructions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/niran_belliappa/archive/2014/01/16/step-by-step-configuring-crm-2013-internet-facing-deployment-ifd.aspx)

You will have to setup `ADFS` and configure `DNS` with a binding certificate. This will allow for claims based authentication to your on-premise crm.

Comment: About the DNS with a binding certificate. what IP Address should I use? Done configuring IFD with ADFS..but when I ping the dns that will be used to access the crm. it can't ping.

Comment: The CRM server and ADFS server needs to be accessable from the internet somehow.

Comment: If you bought a certificate you should have an IP right?